# Counting amino acid sequences by column

Tags: perl, hash, count

I am trying to design a Perl script to find the highest amino acid count found in the same column when comparing different sequences.

Each sequence is already found in its own line or string.

Format example: sequence 1, 2 and 3.

```
KPKFYALDMFPYPSGAGLHVGHPEGYTATDIVARYKRMTGHN-----------VLHPMGW---DAFGLPAEQYA------IETGTHPSQTTVKN------------------VGRFREQLQSLGFSY-D-WDREVATCDA
KPKCYILDMFPYPSGAGLHVGHPLGYTATDILSRFKRMKGFN-----------VLHPMGW---DAFGLPAEQYA------IETGTHPKITTERN------------------IERFRTQLKSLGFSY-D-WDREISTTEP
KPKCYILDMFPYPSGAGLHVGHPLGYTATDILSRFKRMQGFN-----------VLHPMGW---DAFGLPA
```

EQYA------IQTGTHPKFTTAQN------------------IDRFRTQLKSLGFSY-D-WDREISTTEP

I would expect the output to be the highest amino acid found in each of the sequences, `K` and the number of times it appears, (for the first amino acid) while then proceeding to the next amino acid in the sequence (`P`) until `$end amount`.

So far this is what i have written. Any help on how to make it more clear or efficient is apreciated.

I am having problems with the counting part and the moving to the next column for the next count.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

#use diagnostics;

open(S, "Leu Mito Align.txt") || die "cannot open FASTA file to read: $!";
open(OUTPUT, ">output.txt");

my @lines = <S>;
my $lines;
my @seq;
my $seq;
my $line;
my $count;
my $start = 140;    # amino acid column start
my $end   = 150;    # amino acid column end
my $final = 150;    # end of count
my $column;
my @extract;
my $extract;
my $aa = 0;         # get the first amino acid, should increment by one until it reaches end of string, which should be $ae.
my $ae = 1;
my @count;

foreach $seq (@seq) {    #original sequence
  $seq =~ s/^>.*]//g;
  $column = substr($seq, $start, $end); # selects amino acid sequence from $start to $end
  @extract = "$column\n";               # Sequence length

  #print OUTPUT @extract;

  for $extract (@extract) {

    #print OUTPUT $extract;
    $count = substr($extract, $aa, $ae); # Count amino acids individually one   by one until it reaches ae.

    #print $count;
    @count = "$count\n";
    @count = (split /\s/, $count);
```

This is the part where I get stuck. I try to create hashes in order to count the different letters but no luck.

```
while (@count) {
  foreach $AA (@count) {
    $AA++ foreach ($_);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ideally a program should use no global variables at all, but you declare *fifteen* at the top of your program and it forms the majority of your post.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect `@extract = "$column\n"` to do, but it doesn't do anything with the sequence length as your comment says

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing a bit better? I'm looking at what you're saying with `$start` being the _amino acid start column_, but your lines are only 140 columns long. When you say you're _highest amino acid found in each of the sequences_ are you totaling the letters in each line, or are you totaling the columns? Can you give us a bit more data, what you expect, and maybe why you expect those results?

Comment: @Borodin I was trying to make that variable as a temporary keeper of the amino acid letters, so as to count them and then proceed to the next one. I do have to work on my tidying skills and try to remove some of the global variables, thanks!

Comment: @DavidW. Sorry i should have explained, that is part of the code that I Utilize in order to get the target sequence in the example. The original sequence has species name and other data that I did not want so I cropped it out. I want to total the columns one by one, when it is finished with the first column (letter) of X sequences, it should go to the next one (column wise across all the sequences in the list). thank you. I am totalling the columns (same amino acid position), not the letters in the same line (sequence).

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess at what you need. You have given only two sequences as sample data, so choosing a "majority" for each column is pointless. (At any one point, there are either two identical acids with a count of 2, or two different ones, each with a count of 1. So there can never be a majority.). Also, you have said nothing about what to do with hyphens in the sequence strings.

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @counts;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @acids = split //;
  for my $i (0 .. $#acids) {
    my $acid = $acids[$i];
    ++$counts[$i]{$acid};
  }
}

my $max_seq = join '', map {
  my ($chosen_acid, $max_count);
  while (my ($acid, $count) = each %$_) {
    unless ($max_count and $max_count < $count) {
      $chosen_acid = $acid;
      $max_count = $count;
    }
  }
  $chosen_acid;
} @counts;

print $max_seq, "\n";
```

**output**

```
KPKCYILDMFPYPSGAGLHVGHPEGYTATDIVARYKRMKGHN-----------VLHPMGW---DAFGLPAEQYA------IETGTHPKITTVKN------------------VERFREQLKSLGFSY-D-WDREVATCEP
```

Comment: @Gyler: Please let us know whether your question has been resolved.

Comment: I'm playing around with the code to see if it will work for what I have in mind. I added a 3rd sequence to the file for testing purposes. Would I get the maximum count of the amino acid per column by doing a "keys $max_count"? 
Also as for the hyphens, I want to count them, same as the amino acids. Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: Wasn't able to get it to work :(   Let me know if you have any ideas on what i can do, updated the original question a bit, thank you for your help so far!